# "Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Bool' to expected argument "

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I´m having some trouble implementing a SearchBar to my `TableView` with IndexPath.row data

I cannot figure out what to do with this error message:

Cannot convert value of type `(String) -> Bool` to expected argument type `(postStruct) -> Bool`

I get this error message in the `func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)`

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

    struct postStruct {
        let username : String!
        let school : String!
    }

class TableViewProfileController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var posts:[postStruct] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Find friends"
        searchBar.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self


        //Hide backButton in Navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

        // SearchController
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0, blue: 102.0/255.0, alpha:  1.0)
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    // TableView Cell Content
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = snapshotValue!["Username"] as! String
            let school = snapshotValue!["School"] as! String

            self.posts.insert(postStruct(username: username, school: school) , at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        posts = searchText.isEmpty ? posts : posts.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].username
        label1.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 16)
        label1.textColor = UIColor.black

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].school
        label2.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11)
        label2.textColor = UIColor(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 102.0/255.0, alpha:  1.0)


        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Userlogo")

        return cell!
        }


    //Preparing Segue to show username in FindUserViewController
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "findSegue", sender: self.posts[indexPath.row].username)
    }

    //Segue to show username in FindUserViewController
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier! == "findSegue" {
        let guest = segue.destination as! FindUserViewController
        guest.pickedUser = sender as! String

        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = "Back"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the `filter` function to an `postStruct` array, so the syntax is at least

```
posts.filter({ (post: postStruct) -> Bool in ... })
```

or shorter

```
posts.filter { post in ... }
```

You could search for

```
posts = searchText.isEmpty ? posts : posts.filter { post in
        return post.username.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

Side-note:

**Please, please do not - never do – declare implicit unwrapped optional members in a struct**.

Either they are indeed optional then declare them as `String?` or they are non-optional then cut the exclamation mark.

Comment: Thanks.. the error is gone.

Now I just have to figure out why is does not making any search